# Tengo problemas con las rutas relativas en html

Tags: html

Estoy haciendo un trabajo en el cual estoy haciendo rutas relativas con videos, audios y imágenes pero al configurar la ruta en cada uno de los html no me aparecen cuando lo pongo en el navegador ni tampoco en el programa que uso. Adjunto capturas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Nos muestras una ruta donde debe estar la imagen o el video, pero no sabemos si realmente se encuentra en la carpeta indicada ¿existen?

Comment: No uses espacios en las rutas en web, en su lugar te recomiendo usar guiones

Comment: La carpeta si existe con los archivos dentro